# how to judge that a user is really browse to the link or just see the chooser in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

There is a button that redirect the user to the url of Youtube, and I want to know that the user is really browse to the link or just see the chooser in my Android APP?

I tried startactivityforresult() but it doesn't work. Is there any method to do that? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the browser gets opened, The first method that will be called from activity is `onPause()` followed by onStop() i.e. the activity will be paused and then stopped. Check if method `onStop()` get called or not alternatively save a `Boolean` and change its state in `onSop()` method and check its state in onRestart() method this way you will get to know whether browser is opened or not.

like this

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        System.out.println("STOP");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();
        System.out.println("onRestart");

             // check the value of boolean here


    }
```

Comment: when chooser show up onPause() is also called. Instead I use onStop() to judge if browser open or just show the chooser

Comment: show chooser:call onPause() ; open browser:call onPause(), onStop()。
so I judge if browser was opened or not in onStop()